# How can I implement a loop so my program doesn't crash?

Tags: javascript, string, html

I'm a beginner and I have this Javascript problem I'm working on. I'm required to prompt the user to enter either R/r or F/f. However, I want to implement a loop so that in case they enter something else, my program doesn't crash. How would I go about doing this?

```
function CalculatePayroll()
{
employeeNumber=prompt("Please enter the employee number");
employeeName=prompt("Please enter the employee's name");
employeeDepartment=prompt("Please enter the employee's department");
employeesHours=prompt("Please enter the number of hours the employee 
worked");
employeeTypeCode=prompt("Please enter the employee's type code: F/f or 
R/r");

  if(employeeTypeCode=="R"||employeeTypeCode=="r")
  {
    RegularWorkerPayroll();
    CalculateTotalPay();
    DisplayPaySlip();

  }

  else if(employeeTypeCode=="F"||employeeTypeCode=="f")
  {
    FacultyPayroll();
    CalculateTotalPay();
    DisplayPaySlip();
  }
}
```

I would like to have a loop implemented so that if they enter something like "b" or whatever, I can continuously prompt them until they enter the right character. I tried a couple different times but I just ended up with an infinite loop lol.

Comment: Looks like a switch would be more useful in this scenario.

Comment: Recursive call will help with base condition of allowed characters.

Comment: Be sure to show what you've tried already

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop with testing of an array and `includes`. Then use a `switch` and `toLowerCase` for calling functions:

```
employeeTypeCode=prompt("Please enter the employee's type code: F/f or R/r");

while (!["F", "f", "R", "r"].includes(employeeTypeCode)) {
    employeeTypeCode=prompt("Please enter the employee's type code: F/f or R/r");
}

switch (employeeTypeCode.toLowerCase()) {
    case "f":
        FacultyPayroll();
        break;
    case "r":
        RegularWorkerPayroll();
        break;
}

CalculateTotalPay();
DisplayPaySlip();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a while loop like below:

```js
var employeeTypeCode;

while (employeeTypeCode != "r" && employeeTypeCode != "f") {
  employeeTypeCode = prompt("Please enter the employee's type code: F/f or R/r").toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: Make the example specific to the OP's question, rather than an example that they would have to figure out how to modify.

Comment: @JackBashford on it. Thanks for telling me

Comment: No problem @AniketG

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `do-while` loop to get the user input, and keep requesting it if they enter an invalid option.

You can use `.toLowerCase()` on your input so you only need to check the lowercase version of your letter. Then, you can also use an object to map your letters to a particular function which calls the associated function for that `employeeTypeCode`,

```
function calculatePayroll() {
  var options = {
    'r': RegularWorkerPayroll,
    'f': FacultyPayroll
  }

  employeeNumber = prompt("Please enter the employee number");
  employeeName = prompt("Please enter the employee's name");
  employeeDepartment = prompt("Please enter the employee's department");
  employeesHours = prompt("Please enter the number of hours the employee worked ");

  do {
    employeeTypeCode = prompt("Please enter the employee's type code: F/f or R / r ").toLowerCase();
  } while(employeeTypeCode !== "r" && employeeTypeCode !== "f");

  options[employeeTypeCode]();
  CalculateTotalPay();
  DisplayPaySlip();
}
```

Also, it is usually good practice to only use capital letters for function names if it is a constructor function, not a regular function like this one.